# make GitX open via Terminal for the repo laying at the current path

Tags: terminal, gitx

I usually start gitx via the terminal command

```
$ gitx
```

Normally, when I'm at /path/to/repo as pwd in terminal, gitx was opening that repos log. I don't know if it was an update or if I changed some settings, but since some time, gitx opens blank, when i hit the command. I googled, and couldn't find. How do I get gitx to open the repo of the directory, I'm in at that moment?

Thanks!

Comment: you might consider changing the accepted answer now that the latter has received more votes (and is an easier solution than the former)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open terminal, navigate to the site directory and type this at the prompt:

```
$ open -a GitX .
```

**--- edit ---**

To make this change permanent, open your local `.bashrc` file:

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following alias wherever you like:

```
alias gitx='open -a GitX .'
```

Save and exit, then reload the profile:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

All done :) Now you should be able to just type `gitx` in the repo directory (in terminal) and voila, hope it helps.

Comment: Consider updating your answer.

Answer (score 42):

There is a menu option for this in GitX.

```
GitX / Enable Terminal Usage…
```

Comment: @Maitreya It is, now that GitX added this option.

Comment: Please, pay attention that `gitx` itself does it by symlinking to binary from `/usr/local/bin` which looks better and more universal than recommended answer