# Gitx on mac os Sierra: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported

Tags: macos-sierra, gitx

After upgrading to Sierra(10.12) I have an issue with garbage collection within GitX.

```
objc[2253]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.
```

Comment: Possible solution: just use gitx fork https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

Comment: Shane's answer is great but the Gui installation did not work for me. Did a `brew search gitx` and installed the the rowanj cask,`brew install Caskroom/cask/rowanj-gitx`, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I dug around and found this gix fork that appears to be working

https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

Comment: @CodaChang, please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625836/make-gitx-open-via-terminal-for-the-repo-laying-at-the-current-path

Comment: Just for the late that uses homebrew: `brew cask install rowanj-gitx`.