# How can I use Homebrew to get gitx working on macOS Sierra?

Tags: homebrew, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra, homebrew-cask, gitx

If I would try using the following command to install `gitx` on macOS Sierra or High Sierra:

```
brew install homebrew/cask/gitx # DOES NOT WORK on Sierra
```

then my attempt to run `gitx` would result an error like this:

```
objc[41181]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.
```

I already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923100/1283667) but it does not show how to install the rowanj fork using Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

The following command does the trick:

```
brew cask install rowanj-gitx
```

Credit goes to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914454/gitx-on-mac-os-sierra-objective-c-garbage-collection-is-no-longer-supported/39923100#comment71139885_39923100) on [the answer referenced in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923100/1283667).

Comment: Worked for me just now on macOS 10.13.5 (17F77) with Homebrew 1.6.7 (latest stable)